# Erro upload mídia Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mvc, file-upload

Ao tentar fazer o upload de qualquer mídia, o erro seguinte aparece sempre : `O TIPO DE ARQUIVO NÃO É PERMITIDO`. Mas sim, coloquei `jpg`, `png`, `gif`, já mudei apenas para `pdf` e  erro persiste! Segue códigos:

CONTROLLER:

```
class Midia extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        init_painel();
        esta_logado();
        $this->load->model('midia_model', 'midia');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->gerenciar();
    }

    public function cadastrar(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'NOME', 'trim|required|ucfirst');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('descricao', 'DESCRICAO', 'trim');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE):
        $upload = $this->midia->do_upload('arquivo');
        if (is_array($upload) && $upload['file_name'] != null):
            $dados = elements(array('nome', 'descricao'), $this->input->post());
            $dados['arquivo'] = $upload['file_name'];
            $this->midia->do_insert($dados);
        else:
            set_msg('msgerro', $upload, 'erro');
            redirect(current_url());
        endif;

    endif;
    set_tema('titulo', 'Upload de mídia');
    set_tema('conteudo', load_modulo('midia', 'cadastrar'));
    load_template();
    }
```

MODEL:

```
class Midia_model extends CI_Model {

    public function do_insert($dados=NULL, $redir=TRUE){
        if($dados != NULL):
            $this->db->insert('media', $dados);
            if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0):
                set_msg('msgok','Cadastro efetuado com sucesso','sucesso');
            else:
                set_msg('msgerro','Erro ao inserir dados','erro');
            endif;  

            if($redir) redirect(current_url());
        endif;
    }

    public function do_upload($campo){
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpeg|png|pdf';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if($this->upload->do_upload($campo)):
            return $this->upload->data();
        else:
            return $this->upload->display_errors();
        endif;
    }

}
```

VIEW:

```
 switch ($tela) :
        case 'cadastrar':
            echo '<div class="large-12  columns ">';
            echo breadcrumb();
                erros_validacao();


get_msg('msgok');
            get_msg('msgerro');
            echo form_open_multipart('midia/cadastrar',array('class'=>'custom'));
            echo form_fieldset('Upload de midia');  
            echo '<div class="large-7  columns ">';
            echo form_label('Nome para exibição');
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'nome', 'class'=>'five'), set_value('nome'), 'autofocus');
            echo form_label('Descrição');
            echo form_input(array('name'=>'descricao', 'class'=>'five'), set_value('descricao'));
            echo form_label('Arquivo');
            echo form_upload(array('name'=>'arquivo', 'class'=>'twelve'), set_value('arquivo'));
            echo anchor('midia/gerenciar','Cancelar',array('class'=>'button radius alert espaco'));         
            echo form_submit(array('name'=>'cadastrar','class'=>'button radius'), 'Salvar Dados');
            echo form_fieldset_close();
            echo form_close();
            echo '</div>';
    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, esse erro ocorre porque o destino onde o arquivo está sendo enviado está incorreto, ou a pasta de destino está sem permissão para a inserção do arquivo. Procure verificar se a permissão da pasta está 777 e se seu path de destino está correto, sem faltar nenhuma barra ( / ).

Answer (score 0):

Você tem permissão de escrita no diretório onde os arquivos serão salvos?

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

Comment: Sim, tenho total controle da pasta !